# Update with if else statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried using an SQL query below but got an error which says:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'.
```

Here's the SQL query

```
UPDATE TBLGPS 
IF speed >= 0
THEN SET REMARKS = 'Running'
ELSE SET REMARKS = 'Stopped' 
WHERE PLATENO = 'ALCORAN-WIH312' AND TRXTIME = '13:16:20'
```

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

Answer (score 3):

`IF` cannot be used in "regular" SQL Statements, use `CASE` instead:

```
UPDATE TBLGPS 
   set remarks = case
                    when speed >= 0 then 'Running'
                    else 'Stopped'
                 end
WHERE PLATENO = 'ALCORAN-WIH312' 
AND TRXTIME = '13:16:20'
```